# How to attach a number sign in front of a number

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java that asks the user for an employee name and the salary. I need to put a number sign in front of the salary, once it is inputted and displayed on the screen. Any idea how I would go about doing that?

Thanks in advance!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //use default constructor
        //ask name
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is Employee #1's name?");
        //System.out.println(name);
        //ask salary
        double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the employee's salary?"));
        //System.out.print(salary);
        //make an employee1 value
        Employee employee1 = new Employee(name, salary);
        //print out
        System.out.println(employee1);
        System.out.printf("Employee: %s%n", employee1.getName());
        System.out.printf("Salary: %.3f%n", employee1.getSalary());
//      System.out.printf("Employee: %s", employee1.getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's name:" + employee1.getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's salary:" + employee1.getSalary());
        System.out.printf("%.3f", salary);


        //employee 2
        String name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is Employee #2's name?");
        double salary1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the employee's salary?"));
        //System.out.print(salary);
        //make an employee2 value
        Employee employee2 = new Employee(name1, salary1);
        //print out
        System.out.println(employee2);
        System.out.printf("Employee: %s%n", employee2.getName());
        System.out.printf("Salary: %.3f%n", employee2.getSalary());
//      System.out.printf("Employee: %s", employee2.getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's name:" + employee2.getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's salary:" + employee2.getSalary());
        System.out.printf("%.3f", salary);


    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.printf("Salary: # %.3f%n", employee2.getSalary()); ?

Comment: number sign,  what it mean ? are you looking for Currency simbol ?

Comment: What is a "number sign"? Currency symbol? Just have it as part of your prtinf string?

Comment: Do you maybe mean dollar sign? Why not just `"$" + employeet2.getSalary()`?

Comment: What did you try? We expect some effort

Answer (score 1):

If you need locale specific currencies, look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Code excert:

```
static public void displayCurrency( Locale currentLocale) {

    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);
    Currency currentCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

    System.out.println(
        currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ", " +
        currentCurrency.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
}
```

The output generated by the preceding lines of code is as follows:

```
French (France), Euro: 9 876 543,21 €
German (Germany), Euro: 9.876.543,21 €
English (United States), US Dollar: $9,876,543.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not the most dynamic answer, you really can just add whatever character right before you print the salary:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's salary: #" + employee2.getSalary());
```

This would probably work just fine for most cases. Or if instead of number sign you meant dollar sign, you could just replace it in the output statement instead.

Comment: I meant a dollar sign! Sorry! That worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

> '+'   -   -   y4  y   -   The result will always include a sign

You can format your number to always contain a sign

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double s = 47.11;

    System.out.printf("%+.2f%n", s);

    System.out.println(String.format("%+.2f%n", -s));
}
```

**Output**

```
+47,11
-47,11
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line below in the beginning of the main function.

```
String numberSign = "#"; // Whatever you desire
```

then use it with concatenate (it's a '+' for String) where needed.

e.g.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the Employee's salary:" + numberSign + " " + employee2.getSalary());
```